# What's the first vowel of Boston, MA?

Tags: american-english, pronunciation, proper-nouns

The Wikipedia article on [Boston](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boston) states that the first vowel in the name of the city is that of "caught," not "cot," citing Longman Pronunciation Dictionary.  This seems consistent with my own experiences with chatting with Bostonians, who do not merge the two vowels.  Many people around me do merge the two vowels, to whom this question is moot.  How about other Americans who do distinguish "caught" and "cot," in, e.g., the Midwest and the South?  Is the first vowel of "Boston" really the same as "caught" to them as well?

Comment: I'm a native Chicagoan who lived in Boston for many years,  and everyone I ever heard pronounce the name used the *caught* pronunciation.  The only ones who ever used *cot* were those who pretended to mock an imaginary (and false) Boston accent.

Comment: We could cite multiple online dictionaries with the 'caught' = [CLOTH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_set) vowel. Is there other justification that you'd like?

Comment: @Mitch: you could also cite [dictionaries](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=Boston) that give both pronunciations. And [some](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/boston) that don't 
 even give the pronunciation with the *caught* vowel.

Comment: @Mitch Technically, *caught* has the THOUGHT vowel, and *Boston* has the CLOTH vowel. But no American ever distinguishes those two as phonemes.

Comment: @tchrist Hmm... and it seems [many dialects distinguish CLOTH and THOUGHT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet_chart_for_English_dialects)

Comment: @Mitch None in North America do so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your premise is wrong. In the traditional Boston accent, the vowels in *cot* and *caught* are merged, and are both pronounced with the *caught* vowel (although *cart* is pronounced the way the rest of the country pronounces *cot*).

Thus, Bostonians themselves generally pronounce the name of their city /bɔstən/, with the *caught* vowel, even those without the *cot-caught* merger.

If you are to believe the [American Heritage](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=Boston) dictionary, the rest of the country is confused as to how to pronounce it, and can use either pronunciation. I believe this is correct. But note that the rest of the country can't pronounce *Worcester, Woburn, Haverhill, Quincy, Bowdoin, Cochituate* and many other place names near Boston, either.

Comment: Let's see: Wooster (closer to Wusster, I guess), Wooburn, Hayverel, Quinzy, Bohdin, Kohchichuit ...

Comment: @Robusto The Upper Midwest, which doesn't have the merger, also says /bɔstən/, so it sounds bizarre to me every single time I hear somebody say it with the unrounded vowel from *khan*. I also don't notice it when Pittsburghers say it, because their merge is like Boston's and so they round everything. Adding rounding isn't a big deal but losing it always throws me off; I don't know why this perceptual asymmetry should be.

Comment: @tchrist: Pittsburghers really lay into the /ɔ/ even more than the rest of us. I had a friend from there who always called me Rawb.